# Writing a general term

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

What would be the methods and procedures for writing a general term of the following two expressions.

$a=1+ \frac{w^2x^2}{2!}+\frac{w^4x^4}{4!}+.......\infty$ and $b=-x-\frac{w^2x^3}{3!}-\frac{w^4x^5}{5!}-........$, where $w$ is non real, complex cube root of unity. And $!$ denotes factorial.

Actually I've got to find the value of $$(a^2-b^2w^2)$$ so if that plays any role in finding the general term.. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a = \frac{1}{2}(e^{wx}+e^{-wx})$ and $wb = \frac{-1}{2}(e^{wx}-e^{-wx})$. Both follow from $e^z = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}\;$.

Comment: How did you get that?

Comment: @Zlatan Look at the $e^z$ series, then at $e^z + e^{-z}$. The odd powers cancel out since $(-z)^{2k+1} = -z^{2k+1}$, the even powers add up since $(-z)^{2k} = z^{2k}$.